# Joomla getBody regex phenomenon

Tags: php, regex, joomla, joomla1.5

I discovered just recently a weird phenomenon:

After Joomla created the HTML, I try to add some headers. I can't do this before that, because I need some information from the HTML. 
To filter out the headers, I am using a simple regex: `#(<\s*head[^>]*>.*)(<\s*/\s*head\s*>)#ism`, but it does not work.
But if I use `#(<\s*head[^>]*>\s*.*)<\s*body[^>]*>#ism` before that, it suddenly works. Can someone explain me this weird behaviour? Any ideas are welcome.

```
public function onAfterRender()
{
...

$html = JResponse::getBody();

preg_match('#(<\s*head[^>]*>.*<\s*/\s*head\s*>)#ism', $html, $matchWholeBody);
preg_match('#(<\s*head[^>]*>\s*.*)<\s*body[^>]*>#ism', $html, $match);
preg_match('#(<\s*head[^>]*>.*<\s*/\s*head\s*>)#ism', $match[1], $matchFilteredBody);

...
}
```

Result (var_dumps):

```
$matchWholeBody: array(0)
$match[1]: string(3641)
$matchFilteredBody[1]: string(3639)
```

Joomla 1.5.25
php 5.3.2

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing the HTML source to which your regexps are tied to. It's somewhat troubling that you expect to see `\s*` before the tag names. Regex is totally suitable for modifying well-known HTML output, but if it's not even ensured that the tags are minimally normalized then it's no wonder this fails. Albeit it's unclear why just the `.*` might fail. Add `#U` ungreedy though. And again, show some sample html.

Comment: I tried it already without `\s*` but there isn't any change. Doing it ungreedy was a good objection: `preg_match('#(<\s*head[^>]*>.*?<\s*/\s*head\s*>)#ism', $html, $matchWholeBody);` works fine. Thanks Mario!